# Intellij IDEA & JavaFX artifact build does not generate EXE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm trying to build a native JavaFX artifact with the latest Intellij IDEA EAP (Community Edition), but all IDEA does is build a jar out of my classes & images. Even though I have the `.exe` selected in the project structure.

Why doesn't IntelliJ generate the exe-file? Is this an EAP bug or something? Or am I simply missing something here?

I'm quite new to JavaFX and its deployment methods.. should IntelliJ bundle a JRE into the EXE too (provided I happen to get it generate one)? There isn't an option to bundle JRE in the settings...

Comment: It would be a big waste of space to bundle JRE into exe. Why not to use exe4j or something? Why not to create an executable jar it works like exe if you have JRE installed.

Comment: Well I was planning to bundle a stripped down jre with the app.. You can get it very slim, if you strip it down by hand. My app requires Java 8, and www.java.com doesn't even provide it yet! I kind of dislike the idea of relying on a public jre..

Comment: A JRE is not necessarily would be from www.java.com or www.oracle.com but your slim app bundle with JRE will look like a fox in a rabbit hole.

Comment: Well, I'm targeting the average Joe with my app, not developers who tend to have the latest versions of everything installed. And with all the fuzz about Java security, I don't think it's a bad idea to try to hide the fact that I'm using Java.

Comment: Bundle the JRE. A user will happily download a 80Mb EXE. They won't be happy to download and install Java first. It's highly probable that a non-developer user will have no JRE or JDK installed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For some reason, selecting `exe` doesn't work but `all` works. Select `all` and you will be fine. Only bundles for Windows will be created (if that's your OS).

Comment: Weird, I could have sworn that I tried it, and that it did nothing too. But now that I tried it again, it works. Thanks.

Comment: ...however, the exe produced by Intellij does not work. It says could not find main-class, even though I have it set correctly. I guess I shouldn't complain since it's EAP after all. I guess I'm back to manual ant-build for now..

Comment: @user2499946 Did you set `Application class` in `JavaFX` tab and `Main Class` in `Output layout` tab?

Comment: And did you try to run it from command prompt to see whether there are some exception thrown?

Comment: Well I did now.. and it seems that Class.getResource() seems to be the culprit (it can't find a Font actually), so it's my fault after all! I guess I can manage to get it working myself now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can I bundle my application for Linux on a Windows machine somehow?